# Creating composite value using other fields

Tags: jq

Consider this json document

```
$ DATA='{ "url": "https::/abc/", "issues": { "1": { "number": 1}, "2": {"number": 2 } } }'

$ echo $DATA | jq .
{
  "url": "https::/abc/",
  "issues": {
    "1": {
      "number": 1
    },
    "2": {
      "number": 2
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to add a new field, called `extra` to the `issues` object that is a composite of the `.url` field and the `.number` fields.

So the result should look like this

```
{
  "url": "https::/abc/",
  "issues": {
    "1": {
      "number": 1,
      "extra": "https::/abc/1"
    },
    "2": {
      "number": 2,
      "extra": "https::/abc/2"
    }
  }
```

I can get part of the way there with the `.url` field by storing it in the a variable (`$URL`)

```
$ echo $DATA | jq '.url as $URL | .issues[] += { "extra" : "\( $URL )"  } '
{
  "url": "https::/abc/",
  "issues": {
    "1": {
      "number": 1,
      "extra": "https::/abc/"
    },
    "2": {
      "number": 2,
      "extra": "https::/abc/"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem comes with getting access to `.number`.

Just referencing `.number` in the composite value returns `null`

```
$ echo $DATA | jq '.url as $URL | .issues[] += { "extra" : "\( $URL )\( .number )"  } '
{
  "url": "https::/abc/",
  "issues": {
    "1": {
      "number": 1,
      "extra": "https::/abc/null"
    },
    "2": {
      "number": 2,
      "extra": "https::/abc/null"
    }
  }
}
```

next attempt was to try to store `.number` in a variable, but that didn't work

```
$ echo $DATA | jq '.url as $URL | .issues[].number as $NUM  += { "extra" : "\( $URL )\( $NUM )"  } '
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected +=, expecting '|' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.url as $URL | .issues[].number as $NUM  += { "extra" : "\( $URL )\( $NUM )"  }                                          
jq: 1 compile error
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

By using `+=` to update your objects you're losing the context of what you're updating. So naturally you won't be able to reference the *current* item. Instead you should use updating assignment instead. That way `.` refers to the current input and you can reference the other property directly.

```
.url as $URL | .issues[] |= . + { "extra" : "\( $URL )\( .number )"  }
```

Comment: Thanks all for the swift responses. The key ting I was missing was the use of `|=`. Need to find a tutorial that explains this in  more detail.

Comment: It's mentioned in the manual, but the updating assignment operator `|=` ensures that the LHS is `.` in the RHS. For any other assignment operator, `.` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another variable for `.number`, just use `|=` instead of `+=` to keep the context:

```
.url as $url | .issues[] |= .number as $num | .extra = $url + ($num | tostring)
```

Comment: I think you have misplaced the update operator. It's the items of the issues array that need to be updated. In contrast, the extra field can simply be set, as its only variables-based value does not depend on the context. `.url as $url | .issues[] |= .number as $num | .extra = $url + ($num | tostring)`

Comment: @pmf: You are right, updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Store the `.url` into a variable, traverse to the level of the `.issues[]` items, and update `|=` the `.extra` field. Use string interpolation `"\(…)"` or `tostring` or `@text` to convert the numeral into a string, in order to add it to the previously stored url string:

```bash
. as {$url} | .issues[] |= (.extra = $url + "\(.number)")
```

```json
{
  "url": "https::/abc/",
  "issues": {
    "1": {
      "number": 1,
      "extra": "https::/abc/1"
    },
    "2": {
      "number": 2,
      "extra": "https::/abc/2"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BhCqv_H7k59)